# ¿Qué quiere decir "implementaciones de C++"?

Tags: c++

Estoy leyendo un libro sobre C++, y dicen que: *Utilizar las funciones y clases de la biblioteca estándar mejora la portabilidad de los programas, ya que las mismas están presentes en todas las **implementaciones de C++***.

Busqué por Internet y vi que las ***implementaciones de C++*** son: los lenguajes como Visual C++, los IDEs como Code::Blocks, Microsoft Visual C++, etc.

También busqué el concepto de *implementación* (en el contexto de la computación), y aparece lo siguiente: *"una implementación es la realización de una especificación técnica o algoritmos como un programa, componente software, u otro sistema de cómputo"*.

Según yo, ***implementaciones de C++*** hace referencia a lenguajes como Visual C++, e IDEs como las que nombre más arriba; sin embargo, el concepto que encontré sobre "implementación" me hace pensar que tal vez no esté en lo correcto. Por tal razón, me gustaría saber a qué hace referencia las ***implementaciones de C++***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ es un lenguaje que se encuentra en multitud de sistemas y arquitecturas (Windows, Linux, x86, AMD64, ARM, ...).

Pues bien, para cada una de esas combinaciones tenemos una implementación diferente de las librerías que forman parte del estándar de C++. Cada implementación está adaptada a las peculiaridades del sistema para el que está pensada.

Así, una implementación C++ para sistemas Windows tendrá que interactuar con winapi, interfaz que no está disponible en Linux, por lo que las implementaciones para Linux tendrán que hacer uso de otras apis para conseguir el mismo efecto.

Comment: creo que entiendo. Osea, las implementaciones son (por decirlo de alguna forma) como "versiones" del lenguaje (y de las librerías en este caso) que están adaptadas para funcionar en diferentes combinaciones de sistemas operativos y arquitecturas?

Comment: @davidyamd eso es. Pero no hay que confundir implementación con estándar. El lenguaje es cambiante y, actualmente cada 3 años, hay un comité que saca a la luz un nuevo estándar. Cada estándar incorpora cambios al lenguaje. Los últimos estándares han sido c++11, c++14, c++17 y c++20. El número, en este caso, se corresponde con el año de publicación del estándar

Answer (score 2):

C++ es una [especificación estándar](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard), cuyo nombre oficial es:

**ISO International Standard ISO/IEC 14882:2020(E) – Programming Language C++.**

Actualmente está *vigente* la versión 20 de dicho estándar, que está evolucionando constantemente.

Luego hay una variedad de *implementaciones* de este estándar. En lo que estás un poco confundido es que la *implementación* no es el *lenguaje* o IDE en particular, sino que la implementación está dada por

- Las bibliotecas estándar que enlaza un compilador en particular
- El compilador en si

Esto, cumple exactamente con la definición que has encontrado, y que repito aquí:

> una implementación es la realización de una especificación técnica o algoritmos como un programa, componente software, u otro sistema de cómputo

C++ es la especificación. (Visual C++/C++Builder/otra que quieras) es la realización de esa especificación, que utiliza algoritmos y componentes de software específicos que cumplen con los requisitos de la especificación.

La idea básica de esto, es que puedes escribir un programa en C++ estándar, y luego compilarlo para

- diferentes plataformas: Hablamos de procesadores, ya que cada uno tendrá su propio lenguaje máquina, que es el que se produce al compilar un programa c++. Un mismo programa (código fuente) producirá diferentes binarios. No es lo mismo el código máquina de x64 que el de ARM64, por solo mencionar dos.
- diferentes sistemas operativos: Muchas de las llamadas a funciones de la biblioteca estándar se traducen en llamadas al sistema operativo. Manejo de archivos, memoria, redes... un sin número de tareas que se delegan a este. Estamos en una situación similar, un mismo código fuente, producirá diferentes binarios si es para Windows, que si es para Linux, aunque ambos corran en el mismo procesador (digamos, x64).

Dado que hay muchos chips distintos, es común que los fabricantes de chips hagan sus propias implementaciones de C/C++, para ayudar a su adopción.

Sucede más o menos lo mismo con los sistemas operativos.

- Hay implementaciones de C++ que son propietarias y cubren solo un sistema operativo, como la de Microsoft (Visual C++).
- Hay implementaciones propietarias que cubren varios sistemas operativos, como la de Embarcadero (C++ Builder, que nació en la recordada y extinta Borland)
- Hay implementaciones de C++ que son producto de iniciativas de código abierto, como GNU C++